# Ionic React routerLink pass data to another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, routes

I have an Ionic + React project. My question is how can I pass the current data from the loop or map function to the other page or link that I assigned to the `routerLink`. Its because I want the specific data of the loop in order for the other page to display the selected data. Here is my code sample.

```
      <IonList>
          {doctors.map((elem, index) => {
            return (
              <IonItem routerLink="/addAppointment" key={index}>
                <IonAvatar slot="start">
                  <img src={elem['imageUrl']} ></img>
                </IonAvatar>
                <IonLabel >
                  <IonText className="font-weight: bold;">
                    <h2>{elem["name"]}</h2>
                  </IonText>
                  <h3>{elem["speciality"]}</h3>
                  <h4>{elem["email"]}</h4>
                </IonLabel>
                <br></br>
              </IonItem>
            );
          })}
        </IonList>
```

Here is the behavior of the app

[image]

I am new to react and ionic so please bear with me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Integrate redux in your app for the state management. Before navigating to the next page assign the data to some `store variable` and then access this data in the next route.

Comment: is this the only way to do it sir?

Comment: Well this is the best way to do it, trust me :)

Comment: okay will try to integrate redux in ionic + react project.